# Удаление виджетов, размещенных в QLayout

Tags: c++, qt

Есть `QScrollArea` или любой другой виджет. В него добавляются другие виджеты и, соответственно, рисуются на нем. После, этот виджет очищается (удаляются все виджеты на нем), и в него добавляются новые. Но при это не очищается то, что уже вывелось на экран и все выводится поверх старого.
Как визуально очистить виджет?

```
QLayout* scrollLayout = scroll->layout();

for(int i = 0; i < scrollLayout->count(); ++i)
{
    delete scrollLayout->takeAt(i);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как удаляете старые виджеты?

Comment: @Umed Да, удаляю

Comment: да я понял. Я спрашиваю, как удаляете?)

Comment: @Umed приложил код

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg, может вызвать, после удаления виджетов `scrollLayout->repaint();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведенном фрагменте:

```
QLayout* scrollLayout = scroll->layout();

for(int i = 0; i < scrollLayout->count(); ++i)
{
    delete scrollLayout->takeAt(i);
}
```

вы удаляете экземпляры `QLayoutItem` текущего слоя. Их удаление никак не влияет на жизненный цикл виджетов, размещенных в слое, поскольку они фактически принадлежат объекту `scroll`. Из [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#tips-for-using-layouts):

> When you use a layout, you do not need to pass a parent when
>   constructing the child widgets. The layout will automatically reparent
>   the widgets (using QWidget::setParent()) so that they are children of
>   the widget on which the layout is installed.
>
> Note: Widgets in a layout are children of the widget on which the
>   layout is installed, not of the layout itself. Widgets can only have
>   other widgets as parent, not layouts.

Для корректного удаления виджетов необходимо удалять их явно:

```
while (QLayoutItem* item = scrollLayout->takeAt(0)) {
    delete item->widget();
    delete item;
}
```

Если `QLayoutItem` также содержит вложенные элементы слоя, то необходимо проходиться и по ним (можно сделать функцию очистки рекурсивной).