# Как правильно очистить массив из LineEdit(ов)?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Пишу программу на c++ в Qt, и сделал динамическое добавление объектов(а именно LineEdit), и так же создал кнопку для очистки памяти из под объектов, выглядит это так:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QLineEdit>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
QLineEdit *myLine;
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
int n = 1;
int counter = 0;
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()//add new field
{
counter++;
n++;
myLine = new QLineEdit[n];
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(&myLine[counter]);
}




void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()//get result button
{

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()//clear memory button
{
    delete []myLine;
}
```

Но когда я запускаю и добавляю например 3 Line edit и потом нажимаю delete, удаляется только последний добавленный Line Edit, а если нажать еще раз то прога и вовсе крашнется. 
Помогите что делать? Как правильно очищать такие массивы из элементов в Qt?

P.S
также когда я закрываю программу не удалив элементы Qt и компьютер ругается на это, и если я добавляю 3 LineEdit и нажимаю на кнопку очистки один раз, то при закрытии программы все равно комп и qt ругается что говорит мне о том что значит я не все очистил одним разом

Comment: Мне кажется что массив хранит только указатели на Line edit, и когда вы очищаете память - сами Line edit остаются. А если вы нажмёте второй раз - программа попытается очистить массив, который уже удалён, и крашнется.

Comment: @Стас а если я нажимаю на очистку один раз то после закрытия прога ругается типо я не все удалил

Comment: Так же похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607834/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-qlayout